# Asp.Net.Core full customization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to customize identity tables in Asp.net.core. Is it possible to delete tables or columns, use my own tables? I could not find any answer in google or from other devs.

Comment: It is possible. [Microsoft has documentation on their site about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity).

Comment: in documention, it is not written if I can delete column in tables, for example I can inherit IdentityUser class for custom model but I can't delete column of IdentityUser Table itself.

Answer (score 0):

follow this post it is written in a simple and precise way:

[How to add Custom User Properties in Identity Membership System](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-custom-user-properties/)

this is a small example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Identity.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Country
    {
        USA, UK, France, Germany, Russia
    }
}
```